# nodejs file object send to aws s3 with s3.upload or s3.uploadPart

Tags: amazon-s3, upload, aws-sdk, multipartform-data, nodejs-stream

I would like to send my file to amazon S3 that I've taken from client side as multipart/form-data.

In the original doc of s3.upload it expect body as stream like below.
[image]

And for a stream I need to store file into file system and give path.
[image]

Here the question comes.
I have my file object that I've taken from client side as multipart/form-data

```
destination:"uploads"
encoding:"7bit"
fieldname:"file"
filename:"test.zip"
mimetype:"application/zip"
originalname:"test.zip"
path:"uploads\test.zip"
size:4440
```

Is there any way that I send file directly without storing file system?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention form-data method that you're using on nodejs side.
if you're using form-data npm module then you can convert file data into buffer directly using `form.getBuffer()`

Checkout more ref [here](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#buffer-getbuffer)

In case you're using request module to download file do as below:

Use **request-promise** npm module.

```
let rp = require('request-promise');
const fileUrl = 'http://sample.com/file';
const downloadedFile  = await rp(fileUrl);
const fileStreamData = Buffer.from(downloadedFile, 'utf-8');
// Use fileStreamData in S3 upload as Body parameter.
```

Comment: actually I didn't use form-data, I get the file from request and save to file system with multer. after that give the path to buffer and send s3. Are you saying that I can use form data library insted of buffer ?

Comment: Modified answer for request based approach.

Comment: I was using multer for getting the multipart file and configured storage as default like below.
`var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });`

but I realized when you do like that it doesn't give you the original file.
So I've deleted the storage conf and got the original file, after that I was able to access buffer of file than sent 
`var fileStreamData = Buffer.from(file.buffer, 'utf-8');`
thanks btw :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use clean express - you need to read the file input from user - you can use some middleware which will do that for you.
Then you will have the binary `Buffer` and you can directly send it like in example code you provided for S3.upload.